# Fetching database content as it is stored in the table

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to call text arrays exactly as stored as in the database, Here is how my database fields of bank column is stored with bank names :-

State Bank of India

HDFC Bank

ICICI Bank

... and so on

Please note the text cases given above, some words are in uppercase and some has first initial in capital letter. Could anyone tell me how can I echo the text arrays exactly same as stored in the database?

Here is my code :-

```
<?php
include 'db.php';
$bank = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['bank']);
$branch = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['branch']);
$state = str_replace('-',' ',$_GET['state']);
$sql="SELECT * FROM ifsc WHERE bankName='$bank' AND stateName='$state' AND branchName='$branch'";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $bank = $row['bankName'];
        $ifsc = $row['ifsc'];
        $micr = $row['micr'];
        $branch = $row['branchName'];
        $address = $row['address'];
        $telephone = $row['telephone'];
        $city = $row['cityName'];
        $district = $row['districtName'];
        $state = $row['stateName'];
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: What is your current output?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It is coming as lower case

Comment: How do you know that case sensitivity was even maintained in the table?  Are you using a case-sensitive collation?  If you are, then maybe the PHP code is doing something to the data.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen i'm not using case sensitive collation. The problem is may be occurring due to lower case used in the URL opened (text strings). this code is pasted on a branch page that is rendering the data of a bank's branch, e.g. branch name, address, district, state, etc. The current url opened as 

domain.com/abc-branch-state-bank-of-india-delhi-ifsc-code 

if I open the same url as the text strings stored in the databse, it fixes my problem, 

domain.com/abc-branch-State-Bank-of-India-Delhi-ifsc-code

Comment: @VikasKukreja I posted an answer below. If that doesn't fix it and because you "did" in fact execute the query, then let me know so I can just delete my answer. In any case; check for errors with php and on the query. Ping me back as I probably won't be inside the question when you get back. You will also need to update your question with the query/connection for the query.

Comment: @VikasKukreja addendum to the above: You will need to also include the code used for the GET arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't execute the query.

Sidenote: I added an `else{}` to check for errors and replace `$conn` with the variable used for your connection.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// ...
$sql="SELECT * FROM ifsc WHERE bankName='$bank' AND stateName='$state' AND branchName='$branch'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if($result){
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        // ... rest of your code.
        }

}

    } else{

    echo "The query failed: " . mysqli_error($conn);

}
```

You should also use a prepared statement, since your code is prone to an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Use error reporting also:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php